# Adjacent, or side-by-side, graphs from Gnuplot - latex terminal

Tags: graph, latex, plot, gnuplot

Following on from the [Gnuplot tutorial](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs/tutorial.pdf): how can I place graphs, output using the latex terminal, side-by-side; or in a 2x2 grid? I have 4 default-sized graphs at the moment. Will I also have to resize each one by hand?

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \input{plot}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Is [multiplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-20500043.38) an option for you?

Comment: I was hoping to use latex, as I could imagine it as a quicker solution. But I may have to consider multiplot.

Comment: If you want to use latex for this issue, maybe you want to restate your question to a more latex specific audience.

Comment: Thanks for the latex tag. I do hope for a latex answer, but a multiplot or other answer would also be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok if you are using multiplot take a look at [this](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-20500043.38). A little example is also shown below:

```
set key off

set multiplot layout 2,2
plot x**2
plot -x**2
plot x**3
plot -x**3
unset multiplot
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Is there anything in gnuplot like #include? Each of my 4 plots are in different directories, and each with their own titles, labels, tics etc.

Comment: @user643722 Make use of the [LoadPath](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-19700043.31) option.